# Rust map with predicate

Tags: functional-programming, rust

In Rust, is there are map-like equivalent that stops iterating based on a condition I can choose?

I want to iterate over a vector, calling a function on each element as I do so and storing the results, but *stop* iterating if the function return value ever satisfies a condition

Iterative pseudo-code example:

```
results = []
for elem in vec:
    result = foo(elem)
    if result is None
        break
    results.push(result)
```

I can achieve a clumsy equivalent of this with [scan](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.scan) by mutating the initial state but (AFAIK) it will still iterate over every element:

Rust-like pseudo-code for scan variant:

```
results = vec.iter().scan(false, |fail, elem|
    if *fail
        return None

    result = foo(elem)
    if result is None
        *fail = true
    return result
).collect()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
results = vec.iter().map(foo).take_while(|e| e.is_some()).collect()
```

Iterators in Rust are lazily evaluated.  In essence, the call to `collect` forces each element of the iterator to be evaluated one at a time.  This means that as soon as some element fails the predicate in `take_while`, no further elements will be read from the initial iterator, let alone passed through `map`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you should be able to use [Iterator::take_while](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.take_while) for this:

```
results = vec.iter().take_while(|v| foo(v)).collect()
```

Comment: Doesn't that yield the _element_ while the predicate is true, rather than yielding `foo(element)` while the predicate is true?